# How can I secure an emacs-server?

Tags: security, emacs, multi-user, emacsclient

I'd like to ensure that only I can connect to an emacs server that I initialised. I frequently use machines that other people could be SSH'd into, and I don't see what's to stop them opening `emacsclient` and running `M-x kill-emacs` which would screw me over.

I looked at the documentation for `emacsserver` and `emacsclient` but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens out of the box, of course! The Emacs server creates a socket that only you can access (permissions 600 or 700, in a directory with permissions 600 for good measure).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can specify `server-socket-file` for the server and `server-socket-dir` for emacsclient. Simply place the socket in a directory where only you have access and you should be set.